# yuicompressor error, not sure what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, performance, yui-compressor

Very confused here, trying out the yuicompressor on a simple javascript file.

My js file looks like:

```
function splitText(text)
{
    return text.split('-')[1];
}
```

The error is:

[INFO] Using charset Cp1252

[Error] 1:20:illegal character
[Error] 1:20:syntax error
[Error] 1:40:illegal character
[Error] 1:49:missing ; before statement
[Error] 1:50:illegal character
..
..
[Error] 7:3:missing | in compound statement
[error] 1:0:compilation produced 38 syntax errors
...

Can someone please explain to me what is wrong?

Comment: Do you use rhino.jar in your project? If yes, try removing it, because yuicompressor.jar includes the rhino classes too.

Comment: I have no idea, I just downloaded it from the yui site. default installation!

Comment: I am running it from the yuicompressor-2.4.2/build/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar executable.

Comment: Please don't post duplicates of a question.  If you want this to get some answers, try editing it with new information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your encoding of the actual file YUICompressor is acting on is the issue.  Open the file in notepad++ and change to ANSI & it should work.

[http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27732][1]

Comment: Great answer Tim, For the [ERROR] NUMBERS??? :missing ; before statement If you use Aptana go to file properties and choose the right File Text Encoding. I worked for me.. Thanks,